# jquery function to replace a div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a function which on-click hides the first child of the div and and replaces it with another... now the query is on-click `alert(divno)` which should be returning 2 if the divno was 1 but it is returning 11

```
$('#rightarrow').click(function(){
    var getdivname = $('#dcontainer').find("div").first();
    var divid = getdivname.attr("id");
    var divno = divid.match(/[0-9]+/);
    $('#d'+divno).hide();
    divno=divno+1;
    $('#d'+divno).appendTo('#dcontainer');
     alert(divno);
});
```

if I,m using parseInt(divid, 10) it is returning NaN

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: `divno` is a string perhaps.. ?? try with... `parseInt`

Comment: rather than addition it concatinate

Comment: @PsychHalf i tried that too...

Comment: you are using... `parseInt(divid, 10)` and expect to work for `divno` O___O

Comment: and tried `parseInt(divid)` too.... :p

Comment: Don't edit the answer into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a [Unary +](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29) to convert the value of `divno` to an integer rather than string:

```
divno=+divno+1;
```

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't already. For example, y = +x takes the value of x and assigns that to y; that is, if x were 3, y would get the value 3 and x would retain the value 3; but if x were the string "3", y would also get the value 3.

We can prove this by attempting the following tests:

```
"1" + 1     // "11"
+"1" + 1    // 2
```

Comment: i always use  `+` for easy convert string to number.. `+"1"` :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to `parseInt` your `divno` before doing `+1`:

```
divno=parseInt(divno)+1;
```

JavaScript is interpreting your `divno` as a string (because `.match` returns a string) not an integer. doing this forces JavaScript to recognise that it is an integer and not a string.